# Redirect Issue After successfully install patch 8167

Tags: magento-1.9

After successfully install **patch 8167** (with the help of [this](http://www.programmingsimplified.in/2017/06/how-to-install-paypal-security-patch.html) tuto).

During checkout, I redirect to old URL:

> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout....cart_token

instead of a new one:

> https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

I thought, after installing the patch, I will redirect to new URL but still redirect to same old URL.

Answer (score 0):

This patch initially forces http on the link. Because as of 30 June http will no longer be supported in their IPN system.

If your site was already running in HTTPS then this patch is not needed as you are already passing the data over HTTPS